Determine if all EF migrations have been created
I'd like to include a test in our project, to validate that all migrations have been created and committed, to match the DbContext model. This test will be run by the CI pipeline as part of the PR approval.
I've got this test where:

We start a SQL Server test container
We configure the DbContext to use the testconainer
We migrate the database
We use EfCore.SchemaCompare to make sure all required migrations exist

Code
[Fact]
public async Task EnsureAllRequiredMigrationsCreated()
{
    // Arrange
    var msSqlContainer = new MsSqlBuilder().Build();
    await msSqlContainer.StartAsync();

    var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MedicalDataDbContext>()
                  .UseSqlServer(msSqlContainer.GetConnectionString())
                  .Options;

    await using var context = new MedicalDataDbContext(options);
    await context.Database.MigrateAsync();

    var comparer = new CompareEfSql();

    // Act
    var hasErrors = comparer.CompareEfWithDb(context);

    // Assert
    hasErrors.Should().BeFalse(comparer.GetAllErrors);
}

When running this, I get following exception, stating there is a login issue for 'sa':
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
Login failed for user 'sa'.
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, String accessToken, DbConnectionPool pool)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, SqlConnectionOverrides overrides)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open(SqlConnectionOverrides overrides)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Scaffolding.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseModelFactory.Create(DbConnection connection, DatabaseModelFactoryOptions options)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Scaffolding.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseModelFactory.Create(String connectionString, DatabaseModelFactoryOptions options)
   at EfSchemaCompare.CompareEfSql.GetDatabaseModelViaScaffolder(DbContext[] contexts, String connectionString)
   at EfSchemaCompare.CompareEfSql.FinishRestOfCompare(String connectionString, DbContext[] dbContexts)
   at EfSchemaCompare.CompareEfSql.CompareEfWithDb(String configOrConnectionString, DbContext[] dbContexts)
   at EfSchemaCompare.CompareEfSql.CompareEfWithDb(DbContext[] dbContexts)
   at MedicalData.Api.Tests.Component.ComponentTests.Standalone.MedicalDataDbContextTests.MigrationsCreatedTest.EnsureAllRequiredMigrationsCreated() in D:\Dev\MediTool\medicaldata-api-2\tests\MedicalData.Api.Tests.Component\ComponentTests\Standalone\MedicalDataDbContextTests\MigrationsCreatedTest.cs:line 28
   at MedicalData.Api.Tests.Component.ComponentTests.Standalone.MedicalDataDbContextTests.MigrationsCreatedTest.EnsureAllRequiredMigrationsCreated() in D:\Dev\MediTool\medicaldata-api-2\tests\MedicalData.Api.Tests.Component\ComponentTests\Standalone\MedicalDataDbContextTests\MigrationsCreatedTest.cs:line 31
   at Xunit.Sdk.TestInvoker`1.<>c__DisplayClass46_0.<<InvokeTestMethodAsync>b__1>d.MoveNext() in /_/src/xunit.execution/Sdk/Frameworks/Runners/TestInvoker.cs:line 253

When running the same test without migrating (when commenting out the line await context.Database.MigrateAsync();), there is no login issue. Obviously changes are being detected, because the schema hasn't been created. This is the output:

Xunit.Sdk.XunitException
Expected hasErrors to be false because NOT IN DATABASE: Entity 'Address', table name. Expected = Companies
NOT IN DATABASE: Entity 'Article', table name. Expected = Articles
NOT IN DATABASE: Entity 'LocalizedText', table name. Expected = Articles
NOT IN DATABASE: Entity 'Code', table name. Expected = Codes
NOT IN DATABASE: Entity 'LocalizedText', table name. Expected = Codes
NOT IN DATABASE: Entity 'Company', table name. Expected = Companies
NOT IN DATABASE: Entity 'Component', table name. Expected = Components
NOT IN DATABASE: Entity 'Contact', table name. Expected = Companies
NOT IN DATABASE: Entity 'Product', table name. Expected = Products
NOT IN DATABASE: Entity 'LocalizedText', table name. Expected = Products, but found True.
at FluentAssertions.Execution.XUnit2TestFramework.Throw(String message)
at FluentAssertions.Execution.TestFrameworkProvider.Throw(String message)
at FluentAssertions.Execution.DefaultAssertionStrategy.HandleFailure(String message)
at FluentAssertions.Execution.AssertionScope.FailWith(Func1 failReasonFunc) at FluentAssertions.Execution.AssertionScope.FailWith(Func1 failReasonFunc)
at FluentAssertions.Execution.AssertionScope.FailWith(String message, Object[] args)
at FluentAssertions.Primitives.BooleanAssertions1.BeFalse(String because, Object[] becauseArgs) at MedicalData.Api.Tests.Component.ComponentTests.Standalone.MedicalDataDbContextTests.MigrationsCreatedTest.EnsureAllRequiredMigrationsCreated() in D:\Dev\MediTool\medicaldata-api-2\tests\MedicalData.Api.Tests.Component\ComponentTests\Standalone\MedicalDataDbContextTests\MigrationsCreatedTest.cs:line 31 at MedicalData.Api.Tests.Component.ComponentTests.Standalone.MedicalDataDbContextTests.MigrationsCreatedTest.EnsureAllRequiredMigrationsCreated() in D:\Dev\MediTool\medicaldata-api-2\tests\MedicalData.Api.Tests.Component\ComponentTests\Standalone\MedicalDataDbContextTests\MigrationsCreatedTest.cs:line 31 at Xunit.Sdk.TestInvoker1.<>c__DisplayClass46_0.<b__1>d.MoveNext() in //src/xunit.execution/Sdk/Frameworks/Runners/TestInvoker.cs:line 253
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at Xunit.Sdk.ExecutionTimer.AggregateAsync(Func1 asyncAction) in /_/src/xunit.execution/Sdk/Frameworks/ExecutionTimer.cs:line 48 at Xunit.Sdk.ExceptionAggregator.RunAsync(Func1 code) in //src/xunit.core/Sdk/ExceptionAggregator.cs:line 90

This is a .NET 8.0 project. There is a single, initial, migration script, which has been generated and not manually adapted. The application (including the db access) works fine, my issue only occurs in this test; other test fixtures, sharing a common DbContext works fine.
Why does the test fail with Login failed for user 'sa'., only after migrations have been applied?
[edit] Connection string (provided by test container):
Server=127.0.0.1,64834;Database=master;User Id=sa;Password=yourStrong(!)Password;TrustServerCertificate=True


Login failed means your credentials for the DB connection are wrong, it can be a wrong password or a disabled user. Maybe you're using different credentials for running migrations and doing the actual queries.

@Alejandro all this is managed out of the box by the test container. I've included the connection string it generates

Check tht this connection string is actually correct. Use those credentials in SSMS and see if they work. Most likely they're wrong.

Is the goal to check if there are any model changes that is not included in the existing migrations? If so, have you tried context.Database.HasPendingModelChanges()

@JonasH precisely. Thanks, missed this very useful addition to ef core 8
